# Active directory access behalf of trusted entity

Tags: oauth-2.0, active-directory, openid-connect, ping, claims-based-identity

I am really new to Active directory and identity management. We have different authentication strategies for an employee(Windows AD) and customer(Ping AD) handled by separate active directories. Now we have scenario where authenticated employee can process requests behalf of customer and should able to update customer profile in customer AD. I am looking for way that customer AD should trust any authenticated employee from Emp AD and grant him write permission for requested customer. 
Is there any standard practice/way to achieve this ?

Comment: "Trusts" are a feature of Active Directory. A domain can be setup to "trust" another domain. That would allow your employee accounts to be recognized on the customer domain, and you can assign whatever permissions you want to the employee accounts.

Comment: But Stack Overflow is really just for programming questions. This question is probably a better question for [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com), which is for server-administration questions. Or just search Google for ["active directory trusts"](https://www.google.com/search?q=active+directory+trusts).